# Android App won't run, keeps crashing

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am creating an app that views multiple lists and hopefully will be able to search lists. I am a beginner to java and I am sure I have some errors in my code but I want to be able to test it to see if I can create the app. If I find out it's too hard to create I will ditch the project. I am asking because if it is an easy fix and I am close then I would like to see it through. Thanks for the help.

Main Activity

```
package com.rocklandrecycles.rcsw.rcswwheredoirecycle;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Image;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private ImageButton imagebutton1, imagebutton2, imagebutton3, imagebutton4, imagebutton5, imagebutton6;
private EditText SearchBox;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imagebutton1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.metal_button);
    imagebutton2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    imagebutton3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
    imagebutton4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
    imagebutton5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
    imagebutton6 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton6);
    SearchBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_box);
String[] MetalList= {"metal", "metal cans", "aluminum foil", "copper", "steel", "scrap metal",
                        "hangers", "aluminum can", "knife", "exercise equipment"};

    ListAdapter theAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            MetalList);

    ListView theListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.metal_list_view);

    theListView.setAdapter(theAdapter);
    theListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
ListView theListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.metal_list_view);

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String MetalPicked = "Please put in Green Bin";
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, MetalPicked, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public void onMetalButtonClick(View view) {

    Intent getmetalscreenIntent= new Intent(this,
            MetalScreen.class);

    final int result = 1;
    getmetalscreenIntent.putExtra("callingActivity", "Main Activity");
    getmetalscreenIntent.putExtra("MetalActivity" , "MetalList");
    startActivityForResult(getmetalscreenIntent, result);


}
```

}

Manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".MetalScreen"
        android:label="MetalScreen"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>


</application>
```

Metal Screen

```
package com.rocklandrecycles.rcsw.rcswwheredoirecycle;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class MetalScreen extends Activity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.metal_layout);

    Intent activityThatCalled = getIntent();

    String previousActivity =      activityThatCalled.getExtras().getString("callingActivity");
    String previousActivity2 = activityThatCalled.getExtras().getString("MetalActivity");

    ListView callingActivityList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.metal_list_view);


}

}
```

Activity_Main

```
<RelativeLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.rcswwheredoirecyclethisproject.MainActivity"
android:gravity="top"
android:background="@drawable/recyclesymbol">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayout2">

    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/metal_button"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/content"
    android:text="@string/ImageButton1text"
        android:onClick="onMetalButtonClick"
        android:background="@drawable/metal_texture"
        android:maxHeight="10dp"
        android:maxWidth="10dp"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:clickable="true"/>


    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/content"
    android:text="@string/ImageButton2text"
        android:background="@drawable/biohazard"
        android:clickable="true"/>

  <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/content"
    android:text="@string/ImageButton3text"
      android:clickable="true"/>

  <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/content"
    android:text="@string/ImageButton4text"/>

  <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/content"
    android:text="@string/ImageButton5text"
      android:clickable="true"/>

    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/content"
    android:text="@string/ImageButton6text"
        android:clickable="true"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="5"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayout3">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="@string/EditText"
        android:id="@+id/search_box"/>


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout3"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="RCSW Recycle"
     android:textSize="25sp"/>

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Where Do I Recycle This?"
     android:textSize="25sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
<requestFocus />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Metal Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:id="@+id/metal_list_view"
    android:padding="10dp">

</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Stings

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">RCSW Where Do I Recycle</string>
<string name="content">Image</string>
<string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="ImageButton1text">Metal</string>
<string name="ImageButton2text">Hazard</string>
<string name="ImageButton3text">Paper</string>
<string name="ImageButton4text">Glass</string>
<string name="ImageButton5text">Plastic</string>
<string name="ImageButton6text">Other</string>
<string name="EditText">Search Box</string>
<string name="action_settings">RCSWRecycle</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: What is the error you're having? Could you please add your stacktrace.

Comment: Please post your errors and only the code that pertains to the errors.  If you have stack traces / logcat data please post those as well.

Comment: Did you make a copy/paste issue in your main activity? You have several lines repeating and if your code is not compiling is it probably because of that. Remove the 3 lines of code that follow `theListView.setAdapter(theAdapter);`

Comment: Yes I think that was just a copy/paste error. And I will try and paste the errors

Comment: The error I am having is the app is when I try to test it on my device it says "Unfortunatly, RCSW has stopped".

Comment: I also get this "Note: /Users/Thomas/AndroidStudioProjects/RCSWWhereDoIRecycle/app/src/main/java/com/rocklandrecycles/rcsw/rcswwheredoirecycle/MainActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details."

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any Listview in your ActivityMain xml layout file and yet, your onCreate method is calling it and setting the adapter! You are probably getting a nullpointer on your theListView?

You're calling it twice:

```
ListView theListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.metal_list_view);
```

That returns null because android can't find the view on the activity_main.xml.

Edit:
When you start up your Main Activity you can only use the elements on your activity_layout. Since your ListView is on metal layout and not on activity_layout you cannot make a reference to it.

What you need to do is find that view on your metal activity. Like so.
Your on create MEthod of your MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imagebutton1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.metal_button);
    imagebutton2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    imagebutton3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
    imagebutton4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
    imagebutton5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
    imagebutton6 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton6);
    SearchBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_box);



}
```

And then on your Metal Activity you should have something like this: (it is in this layout that you find the listview, create and set the adapters)

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.metal_layout);

        Intent activityThatCalled = getIntent();

        String previousActivity =      activityThatCalled.getExtras().getString("callingActivity");
        String previousActivity2 = activityThatCalled.getExtras().getString("MetalActivity");

        ListAdapter theAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            MetalList);

String[] MetalList= {"metal", "metal cans", "aluminum foil", "copper", "steel", "scrap metal",
                            "hangers", "aluminum can", "knife", "exercise equipment"};

    ListView theListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.metal_list_view);

    theListView.setAdapter(theAdapter);
    theListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String MetalPicked = "Please put in Green Bin";
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, MetalPicked, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });


    }
```

Comment: The ListView double is a typo when moving the code. And I have the ListView in my metal_layout.xml. Do I have to call it a different way because its another screen? And to be honest I don't really know where to find the errors.

Comment: Errors can be found in the console. Cmd+6 if you're running Android Studio on a Mac (ctrl+6 on Windows). Also, check edit, i've added some more info.

Comment: My errors are going crazy there. It is nonstop red info. And I will take a look thanks.

Comment: Post your error log on your original question. Also you should do what i recommended in this answer and check if the error persists. You're probably going to have other error but at least you get your app running.

Comment: I tried the code you put in and it still won't run. Error log is literally way to long to paste in and is still updating

Comment: That is not the error log. It is the normal log. Its the log of the events that are happening in your device/emulator. You only need to copy the portion that belongs to the crash itself, probably the red lines that appear then the app crashes.

Comment: Yes I set it to Errors only. this line keeps popping up a lot 07-13 11:59:27.984      295-295/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
07-13 11:59:28.434     923-1360/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 1150

Comment: That does not look related to your app. Try filtering for the name of your app

Comment: Yeah, set the filters in your log. Filter by application name and then put the name of your package.. com.rocklandrecycles.rcsw.rcswwheredoirecycle maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Rui Santos is correct. You only have access to the xml elements from the file defined in the activity's `setContentView()` method. In this case, in your main activity you declare `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`.

Later you call `findViewById(R.id.metal_list_view)`, but the id `metal_list_view` is in `metal_layout`. `findViewById` searches `activity_main`, fails to find `metal_list_view` and then returns `null`. When you attempt to cast that null to a `ListView` it will throw a `NullPointerException`.

If you are getting some error other than an NPE you should let us know and we'll help with that, but that problem needs to be fixed either way.

### To continue with two activities:

You should be able to get it running by moving

```
String[] MetalList= {"metal", "metal cans", "aluminum foil", "copper", "steel", "scrap metal",
                    "hangers", "aluminum can", "knife", "exercise equipment"};

ListAdapter theAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        MetalList);

ListView theListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.metal_list_view);

theListView.setAdapter(theAdapter);
theListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    ListView theListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.metal_list_view);

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        String MetalPicked = "Please put in Green Bin";
        Toast.makeText(MetalActivity.this, MetalPicked, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // edited to remove outdated reference to MainActivity
    }
});
```

from your main activity's `onCreate()` to your metal activity's `onCreate()`

### Edit:

Somewhat unfortunately, activities and fragments in Android are tightly coupled to their xml layouts. Each activity or fragment only holds a reference to a single layout, with the exception that a layout that contains a frame element can contain other layouts. In this case, your metal activity is coupled to your layout that has the 'listview' you are trying to modify, so the modifications will need to happen in the metal activity. I didn't really try to figure out what your intention was with this, but what you may want is a single activity with two fragments. Then each fragment has a single layout, and the activity holds a reference to both fragments, and with the use of some callback interfaces you can communicate between the three and host all of your logic in your activity.

### Alternately

Taking a closer look at what you are doing, you may want to put a `framelayout` in your main activity layout, convert your metal activity to a fragment, and attach the fragment to your `framelayout`. That will give you a sort of activity-within-an-activity feel that may promote reusability down the line. It's hard to say without knowing what you're going for.

Comment: I am trying to open the Metal List in a new page when the Metal Image button is clicked. Do you think you could help me with the code to fix that part so it works for both layouts?